# Memory allocated to main class executed from servlet?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I have a servlet with execute a class with main method(), which you can typically start via the command line.

In a web container like tomcat, weblogic server, the web container will has its own defined heap space and number of threads to execute the request sent by the web application.

If I start a class with a main method() in my servlet, what will be the memory and threads allocated to this class?

Comment: How would you "start a class with a main method"? Via `MyClass.main()` or via `Runtime.exec()`?

Comment: @piet.t started with MyClass.main()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When invoking the method via calling `MyClass.main()` (as you stated in the comment) it does not matter that you method is called `main` - it will just be like any other method-invocation. A such

- Any memory used during the execution will be allocated on tomcat's heap
- execution will in the thread that processes the servlet-request. So the servlet will not continue processing until `main()` exits.

The easiest way you could use storage that is not from tomcat's heap would be to spawn a new VM-process via `Runtime.exec()` and run your program there. This will result in quite some overhead as starting a VM can take a while.

If you are OK with running in tomcat's VM but want to execute your task in parallel to the servlet-processing you have to implement your own thread-handling.

Comment: In this case, it will leads to threads starvation as I have many such request. My client invokes on my servlet and is dependent on my servlet to return some results back, but the processing it taking a long time. Is there anyway I can implement an asynchronous servlet and return the results to the client when the processing is completed?